# CFRunLoopRun() vs [NSRunLoop run]

Tags: macos, foundation, core-foundation, nsrunloop, cfrunloop

I have an NSRunLoop object, to which I attach timers and streams. It works great. Stopping it is another story alltogether.

I run the loop using `[runLoop run]`.

If I try to stop the loop using `CRunLoopStop([[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] getCFRunLoop])`, the loop won't stop. If I start the loop using `CRunLoopRun()` instead, it works. I have also made sure that the call is made on the correct thread (the one running my custom run loop). I have debugged this with `pthread_self()`.

I found a mailing list archive, where a developer said "don't bother using `CRunLoopStop()` if you started the loop using the run method of `NSRunLoop`". I can understand why it is the way it is - you normally pair up initializers and finalizers from the same set of functions.

How do you stop an `NSRunLoop` without "resorting to CF"? I don't see a `stop` method on `NSRunLoop`. The docs says that you can stop a run loop in three ways:

1. Configure the run loop to run with a timeout value
2. Tell the run loop to stop using `CFRunLoopStop()`
3. Remove all input sources, but this is an unreliable way to stop the run loop because you can never know what stuck what into the run loop behind your back

Well, I already tried 2. and there's an "ugly" feel to it, because you have to dig into CF. 3. is out of the question - I don't fancy non deterministic code.

This leaves us with 1. If I understand the docs correctly, you cannot "add" a timeout to an already existing run loop. You can only run new run loops with a timeout. If I run a new run loop, it will not solve my problem, as it will only create a nested run loop. I'll still pop right back into the old one, the same I wanted to stop... right? I might have misunderstood this one. Also, I don't want to run the loop with a timeout value. If I do, I'll have to make a trade off between burning CPU cycles (low timeout value) and responsiveness (high timeout value).

This is the setup I have right now (pseudo code-ish):

**Communicator.h**

```
@interface Communicator : NSObject {
    NSThread* commThread;
}

-(void) start;
-(void) stop;
@end
```

**Communicator.m**

```
@interface Communicator (private)
-(void) threadLoop:(id) argument;
-(void) stopThread;
@end

@implementation Communicator
-(void) start {
    thread = [[NSThread alloc] initWithTarget:self 
                                     selector:@selector(threadLoop:)
                                       object:nil];
    [thread start];
}

-(void) stop {
    [self performSelector:@selector(stopThread)
                 onThread:thread
               withObject:self
            waitUntilDone:NO];
    // Code ommitted for waiting for the thread to exit...
    [thread release];
    thread = nil;
}
@end

@implementation Communicator (private)
-(void) stopThread {
    CRunLoopStop([[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] getCFRunLoop]);
}

-(void) threadLoop:(id) argument {
    // Code ommitted for setting up auto release pool

    NSRunLoop* runLoop = [NSRunLoop currentRunLoop];

    // Code omitted for adding input sources to the run loop

    CFRunLoopRun();
    // [runLoop run]; <- not stoppable with 

    // Code omitted for draining auto release pools

    // Code omitted for signalling that the thread has exited
}
@endif
```

What am I to do? Is it common/a good pattern to mess around with CF? I don't know Foundation well enough. Is interfering in the CF layer possibly dangerous (with respect to memory corruption, inconsistencies, memory leaks)? Is there a better pattern to achieve what I am trying to achieve?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're doing well. There's not problem to use CoreFoundation when you cannot achieve your goal with Foundation. As CoreFoundation is C, it's easier to mess up with memory management but there is no intrinsic danger in using `CFRunLoop` rather than `NSRunLoop` ([sometimes it may even be safer](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Multithreading/RunLoopManagement/RunLoopManagement.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000057i-CH16-SW26): `CFRunLoop` API are thread-safe whereas `NSRunLoop` isn't).

If you want to stop your `NSRunLoop`, you can run it using `runMode:beforeDate:`. `runMode:beforeDate:` returns as soon as an input source is processed so you don't need to wait until the timeout date is reached.

```
 NSRunLoop *runLoop = [NSRunLoop currentRunLoop];
 NSDate *date = [NSDate distantFuture];
 while ( !runLoopIsStopped && [runLoop runMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode beforeDate:date] );
```

Then, to stop the run loop, you just need to set `runLoopIsStopped` to `YES`.

Comment: Ah, clever! I did not see that `runMode` ran only once. Is there a significant performance penalty incurred by starting the run loop over and over again?

Comment: No, there isn't: that is how `-[NSRunLoop run]` and `-[NSRunLoop runUntilDate:]` work.

Comment: The thread won't stop if you just set runLoopIsStopped to YES.

You need to set it to YES and perform an action on that runloop's thread, otherwise the [runLoop runMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode beforeDate:date] would not exit.

This took me ages to figure out.